# How to create session with php curl in mediawiki api

Tags: php, session, curl, mediawiki-api

I am working on mediawiki api and i want to create user login with api . I referred this [link](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login). But i am not able to create session .

here is my code

**first step**

i have created a session id with this

```
session_start();
    $data = "action=login&lgname=Wiki&lgpassword=gjnlt&lgtoken=5ae555656110dd20a2b0504e4d7e35e0";  // login
    $result=call($data);   // get the session id
    function call($data=null)
    {
        $ch = curl_init('http://192.168.1.32/Eb_new/mediawiki/api.php?format=json');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
        );

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        return $result=json_decode($result);
    }
```

The response i got is .

```
{"login":{"result":"Success","lguserid":5,"lgusername":"Wiki","lgtoken":"d85fd0201276632858ce4ad3ac351de4","cookieprefix":"EB_new_wiki_","sessionid":"3b8cdab43d4cda6b4548a3cc27604e20"}}
```

**second step**

now I have a session id in `$result->login->sessionid` .To set the session i made another call to set session like this

```
setsession($result->login->sessionid);   // set the session

function setsession($sessionid)
{
        $field_array= array(
      'Accept' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT',
      'Accept-Charset' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET',
      'Accept-Encoding' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING',
      'Accept-Language' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE',
      'Connection' => 'HTTP_CONNECTION',
      'Host' => 'HTTP_HOST',
      'Referer' => 'HTTP_REFERER',
      'User-Agent' => 'HTTP_USER_AGENT',
      'Set-Cookie'=>'enwikiSession='.$sessionid.' ;domain=http://192.168.1.32/Eb_new/mediawiki'
      );

    $curl_request_headers=array();

    foreach ($field_array as $key => $value) {
       if(isset($_SERVER["$value"])) {
          $server_value=$_SERVER["$value"];
          $curl_request_headers[]="$key: $server_value";
       }
    };
    $curl_request_headers[]="Expect: ";

    session_write_close();
    $data = "action=login&lgname=Wiki&lgpassword=gjnlt&lgtoken=5ae555656110dd20a2b0504e4d7e35e0";  // login
    $ch = curl_init('http://192.168.1.32/Eb_new/mediawiki/api.php?format=json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_request_headers);
    //curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'enwikiSession='.$sessionid.' ;domain=http://192.168.1.32/Eb_new/mediawiki');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

but the user is not logged in . Where i am wrong . any help will be appreciated . thanks

Comment: You omitted the second response. It might contain a `NeedCaptcha` error. Also, you are setting an `enwikiSession` cookie, but is your target wiki actually called enwiki? In general, [OAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/For_Developers) (e.g. [Extension:OAuthAuthentication](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuthAuthentication)) is usually a better way than mucking around with the login API.

Answer (score 0):

Structure of login request

Send a login request using POST (GET requests will cause an error).

api.php?action=login&lgname=Bob&lgpassword=secret [try in [ApiSandbox]
][1]
Result

```
{
"login": {
    "result": "NeedToken",
    "token": "b5780b6e2f27e20b450921d9461010b4",
    "cookieprefix": "enwiki",
    "sessionid": "17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558e"
}
}
```

The body of the POST can be empty. This request will also return a session cookie in the HTTP header

```
(Set-Cookie: enwikiSession=17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558e; path=/; domain=.wikipedia.org; HttpOnly)
```

that you have to return for the second request if your framework does not do this automatically. The sessionid parameter was added in MediaWiki 1.17 and later.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=login&lgname=Bob&lgpassword=secret

Comment: I am using post method . check my question

Comment: I have give Example  of post method , above  give request will be send via Post methods

Answer (score 0):

I found you have not started session anywhere in above code.

You need to add `session_start()` on every page where you want to **retrieve  value session** or **set value to session**.

[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: I have started it on the top but not mentioned in question. Sorry for that